# UITextField text alignment in ios 4.2

Tags: objective-c

I have a strange problem.

```
UITextField *txtField;
txtField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

This code works well in ios 3.0 & 4.0.(the cursor blinks in the center & textAlignment while typing text is also in center)

However, in ios 4.2, text Alignment remains center but the cursor blinks in the left.

Answer (score 1):

works fine for me on ios 4.2. 
cursor is in center and wents to right on writing.

```
text = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80.0, 8.0, 210.0, 30.0)];
text.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
text.delegate = self;
text.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
text.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

this is my code